# Como hacer que un botón se mueva aleatoriamente en una aplicación forms visual basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual

Quiero que al poner el cursor encima del boton "NO" se mueva aleatoriamente,se sobre programación, pero solo en c++ y python, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace NICOL
{
    public partial class Nicolapp : Form
    {
        public Nicolapp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
        //Simulate left mouse button press 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        //Simulate left mouse button up 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        //Simulate mouse right click 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
        //Simulate the right mouse button up 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
        //Analog mouse button press 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
        //Analog mouse middle button lift 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
        //Indicate whether absolute coordinates are used 
        const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ya sabia que dirias que Si uwu :v");
        }

        private void NO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1500);//1.5 Segundos para mover el mouse, aqui me da error
            SetCursorPos(1414, 117);//Posicion a donde  vas a enviar tu texto o pulsaciones y me da error
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SendKeys.Send("^v");//Aqui un ejemplo de pegar un texto
        }
        public event System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler MouseMove;


    }
}
```

Si pueden me envían el código para copiarlo directamente, muchas gracias por darse el tiempo de leerlo :)
[image: Este es el exe que se debería ejecutar]

[image: El error que me aparece]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo estás complicando demasiado.

El siguiente código debería ser suficiente:

```
public partial class Nicolapp : Form
{
    public Nicolapp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ya sabía que dirías que Sí uwu :v");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evento "Mouse > MouseEnter" al botón.
    /// </summary>
    private void NO_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveButton();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evento "Focus > Enter" al botón.
    /// </summary>
    private void NO_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Con esto, aseguras que no podrá llegar al botón con el teclado
        button1.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Función que relocaliza al botón.
    /// </summary>
    private void moveButton()
    {
        int windowWidth = this.Width, windowHeight = this.Height,
            buttonWidth = NO.Width, buttonHeight = NO.Height;
        Random rndm = new Random();
        int posX = rndm.Next(0, windowWidth - buttonWidth), posY = rndm.Next(0, windowHeight - buttonHeight);

        NO.Location = new Point(posX, posY);
    }
}
```

Asegurándote además de establecer las siguientes **Propiedades** en el botón:

- `UseMnemonic`: False
- `TabStop`: False